# How to implement some screen using inheritance in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My project is a todo app and I have these parts:

1. Meetings
2. Checks
3. Alarms

and all of these parts have a details screen, add screen, list screen, edit screen and search screen.

I'm tired of creating a separate screen for each section, so I need a way to implement all these screens using inheritance and less code.

Any idea will be great.

Comment: share what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

Set `Navigator` route to screen with an `argument` for the part type you want to render (e.g. `Meetings`).

Receive that `arg` in the new screen, then render specific widgets based on that.

For example, set the `Navigator` to pass the part:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
        DetailsScreen.routeName,
        arguments: 'details',
        );
```

Then in the new screen, use the `argument` to render the rest of the page:

```
final sourcePage = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String; 
// passed from last page
```

You can use this var to render different elements in the page:

```
return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('$sourcePage'),
                backgroundColor: sourcePage.toLowerCase() == 'details'
                        ? Colors.green
                        : Colors.black26,
                ),
        );
```

[image: Screenshot of "DetailsScreen.dart" with post logic implemented]